# Moving commits to another branch

Tags: git

Is there any chance to get from:

```
A (master)
 \
  B - C - D (test)
```

to:

```
A - C - D (master)
 \
  B (test)
```

like e.g. (.txt):

```
Commit A: A
Commit B: AB
Commit C: ABC
Commit D: ABCD
```

but I want it to be

```
Commit A: A
Commit B: AB
Commit C: AC
Commit D: ACD
```

Comment: You can cherry pick the *content* of `C` and `D` onto master, then reset `test` back to `B`, but now they have new parents they'll be different commits `C'` and `D'`

Comment: This is a job for [git rebase](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing)

Comment: @jonrsharpe how do I cherry pick the content of a commit?

Comment: I'd suggest googling "git cherry pick"; it's `git cherry-pick`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly what you want to do:

1. Switch to master branch:
   `git checkout master`
2. New branch C:
   `git checkout -b C_BRANCH`
3. Get C commit:
   `git cherry-pick C`
4. Switch to master:
   `git checkout master`
5. Get D commit:
   `git cherry-pick D`
6. Merge CD:
   `git merge -m"D" C_BRANCH`
7. Switch to test branch
   `git checkout test`
8. Reset branch to commit B
   `git reset --hard B`
9. Delete unused branch
   `git branch -d C_BRANCH`